# is it a good practice to overfit your deep learning model on just one data instance for testing the correctness

Tags: tensorflow, optimization, deep-learning, object-detection

Currently i am implementing an object detection model for face detection , and tried training my model on just one single instance of data. (Input : image , target : labels).
But after training my model for a long time, its not able to converge optimally. or in other words i should say it was achieving a saddle point from which it couldnt come out. So i was wondering whether its because the data is just one instance and model is somehow not able to learn or something is wrong with my loss function .

I am using yolo architechture and yolo like loss function to train my model. 
Adam optimizer for minimizing the loss over time.

thanks,

Comment: Your question is not clear, can you specify what are you getting as loss function, and if your model is able to detect the face in the image you give him ? can you for example show what is the detection he is making on this image after the training ?

Comment: So basically , i am having 4 terms (localisation loss , object loss , no object loss and class loss) which add up to give my total loss for an batch instance , but they way they are calculated is bit different than how yolov2 loss function is defined.  Also the detection i am getting are not that good , but that i mean , training and testing on just one image should ideally give very precise detections but its not that good.

Comment: yolo can learn one data for sure, that means your loss function implementation has some issues, please share your loss function. Also explain how you conclude you are into a saddle point!

Comment: @RakeshBalhara my loss function is much more similar to how yolov2 does it , only difference is the scale and the way localisation loss is calculated to eliminate the NaN issues i was facing. And the way i know it is a saddle point is based on observation that loss is stagnant for a long time so rate of loss per epoch is almost zero and also by looking at the graph of the loss function .